# Trying to get result from more than one api React native in the same page

Tags: react-native

i m trying to get data from database and put it inside a picker when i use one fecth it work fine but when i add the second one it get an error says " typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource2.map')  "

```
componentDidMount() {

  fetch('url1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,

      }
      );
    })
     .then( () => {
      fetch('url2')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource2: responseJson
      });
    })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

first picker :

```
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ar1: itemValue})} >

        { this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
        <Picker.Item label={item.nom} value={item.nom} key={key} />)
        )}

      </Picker>
```

second picker :

```
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ar2: itemValue})} >

        { this.state.dataSource2.map((item, key)=>(
        <Picker.Item label={item.nom} value={item.nom} key={key} />)
        )}

      </Picker>
```

Comment: Its important to remember that map() requires you to return something withing the ()

Comment: i didnt have a problem at all in pickers , the main cause of the error is fetch , because when i try to use one fetch it work fine , but when i add the second it didnt work

Comment: Please also attach where you initialize `this.state.dataSource2`.

Comment: dataSource2 is inisialised inside the second fetch and i use this.state.dataSource2 inside the second picker

Comment: Either your initial data for `dataSource2 ` is not an array or you are not getting an array from second call.

Comment: can you tell me please if my second fetch is correct